How can I keep the "Nock Point" on my bowstring from flattening?
I have created an archery bow model, and rigged it accordingly following a few tutorials. Unfortunately, I still have an issue: when I use the "string" bone to pull it, the string mesh has a flat area instead of being a clean angle at the point of the bone. I have been trying to correct it by altering the weight painting, but I can't seem to get it so the string doesn't deform in some way after adjusting it, and I still haven't achieved the clean angle at the nock point. I have used the IK and Distance Limit modifiers as instructed in the tutorials, which seem to give the bow model the desired movement and deformation, but this bowstring issue is persistent. I even tried making a new string mesh and the result was the same. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.




How did you make the bowstring? I think we'll need to see your Blend file to see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

I tried to recreate the bow string in Blender. It seems to be the weight paint, although I do not know how it affects it.
